# Correspondence between class group of binary quadratic forms and the narrow class group via Dirichlet composition: an elementary approach?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, binary-quadratic-forms

I have been trying to explore and learn about connections between the form class group and the ideal class group. To be on the same page, we define the *form class group* of a negative discriminant $D \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 4$ to be the set $C(D)$ of classes of primitive positive definite integral binary quadratic forms (an assumption I make about all forms in this question) under proper equivalence, where two such forms $f, g$ are *properly equivalent* if there exists a matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
p & q\\
r & s\\
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ for which $g(x, y) = f(px+qy, rx+sy)$. I know that the set of proper equivalence classes can be given a group structure under Dirichlet composition: where for two forms $f(x, y):= ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ and $g(x, y):= a'x^2+b'xy+c'y^2$, we define their *Dirichlet composition* to be the form
$$F(x, y) := aa'x^2 + Bxy+ \frac{B^2-D}{4aa'}y^2$$
where $B$ is the unique integer in the interval $[0, 2aa')$ satisfying the following system of linear congruences
$$B \equiv b \pmod{2a}, \hspace{5mm} B \equiv b' \pmod{2a'}, \hspace{5mm} B^2 \equiv D \pmod{4aa'}.$$

Most of the resources I could access give correspondence between the form class group and the whole ideal class group using the notion of orders (a notion that I am not comfortable with). However, I have been particularly interested in the concise treatment in these notes ([https://www.renyi.hu/~gharcos/heegner.pdf](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Egharcos/heegner.pdf)) [Appendix, pages 384-386], which give a bijective correspondence between the form class group and the narrow class group (by the narrow class group, I mean the set of equivalence classes of fractional ideals under the equivalence relation $I \stackrel+\sim J$ if there exist totally positive $\alpha, \beta \in \mathcal O_K$ such that $\alpha I = \beta J$, with this set of classes given a group structure by multiplication), by considering a set of representatives
$$Q_i(x, y) := a_i x^2 + b_i xy + c_i y^2 = a_i (x - z_i y) (x - \overline z_i y), \hspace{1mm} \text{ for all  }i= 1, \cdots, h(D),$$
$$a_i>0, \hspace{1mm} z_i = \frac{-b_i+\sqrt D}{2 a_i}, \hspace{1mm} \overline z_i = \frac{-b_i-\sqrt D}{2 a_i},$$
of the equivalence classes of forms of fundamental discriminant $D$, and then demonstrating that each fractional ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)$ is equivalent to one of the fractional ideals
$$I_i = \mathbb Z + \mathbb Z z_i, \hspace{6mm} i= 1, \cdots, h(D),$$
while the distinct $I_i$ themselves are pairwise inequivalent.

The proof goes by considering an arbitrary fractional ideal $I = \mathbb Z \omega_1 + \mathbb Z \omega_2$ with $\overline \omega_1 \omega_2 - \omega_1 \overline \omega_2 > 0$
and associating to it, the binary quadratic form
$$Q_I(x, y) := \frac{(x \omega_1 - y\omega_2)(x \overline \omega_1 - y \overline \omega_2)}{N(I)},$$
where $N(I)>0$ is the absolute norm of $I$. What I really like about the proof is that it is elementary and doesn't use notions of orders or congruence subgroups.

Now, I have been trying to see if I can motivate Dirichlet composition from this bijection by transport of structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure), but nothing I tried so far has worked. So my question is the following:

Can I show (without using any additional machinery such as orders or congruence subgroups, if possible) that for two ideals $I$ and $J$, the form $Q_{IJ}$ that gets associated to the product $IJ$ under the above correspondence is exactly the Dirichlet composition of $Q_I$ and $Q_J$?

I would be really grateful for suggestions, solutions or references where this has been worked out in detail (with the aforementioned restriction on the machinery used). Thank you.

Comment: see my http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/BLOG_2014_July_15.pdf  the references were

Comment: Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms... Cohen, A Course in Computational Algebraic NUmber Theory...  Franz Halter-Koch, Quadratic Irrationals.  Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$    Given your interest, I can suggest the recent Lehman,   https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Comment: @Will Jagy Thank you so much. I will check these out as soon as I can, and let you know if I have further questions.